# In multi connection universe , " query cannot run due to incompatible objects" error occurs when objects From both DB is brought in

Tags: business-objects

In the multi-connection universe, the below error occurs when objects from both DB is brought in:

> query cannot run due to incompatible objects

One is a derived table and from reference database, I bring in reference data. I joined using a common data column since there is no PK /FK relation between both.

I published the universe and when creating a report I get this error.

Comment: Does your universe contain contexts?  If so, the join between those tables must be in at least one context.